# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/XPathAPI

Tags: java, xalan

I am executing a class in eclipse through main, and as I result I am getting this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/XPathAPI
```

I am using jRE6.

Please help me in solving this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you have `xalan-2.7.1.jar` on your build path.

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar

Comment: please provide me the url of this archieve

Answer (score 3):

You must add the [apache xpath library](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xpath_apis.html) to your class path.